# Is there a way to move adjust a pushpin position manualy on windows phone 8 using bing maps?

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am working on a windows phone 8.0 application wich uses bing maps. I wnat to add a push pin with my current location. So far soo good. What I do not manage to do is to move that pin. More precisely, I want to tap that pin and to mo move it otherwhere on the map.

I tried with events like ManipulationStarted, ManipulationDelta, ManipulationCompleted and other resources on the web, but no results yet.

My C# code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        Pushpin pin = new Pushpin();
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetCurrentPosition();
        }

        async void GetCurrentPosition()
        {
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50; 
        Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Grid MyGrid = new Grid();
        MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        MyGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        MyGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);            

        pin.Content = "I'm a pin";
        pin.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple);
        pin.ManipulationDelta += pin_ManipulationDelta;
        pin.ManipulationStarted += pin_ManipulationStarted;
        pin.ManipulationCompleted += pin_ManipulationCompleted;

        MyGrid.Children.Add(pin);

        //Creating a MapOverlay and adding the Grid to it.
        MapOverlay MyOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        MyOverlay.Content = MyGrid;

        MyOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude, geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude);
        MyOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0, 0.5);

        MyMap.Center = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate(geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude, geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude);
        MyMap.ZoomLevel = 16;
        MyMap.CartographicMode = Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapCartographicMode.Road;

        MapLayer MyLayer = new MapLayer();
        MyLayer.Add(MyOverlay);
        MyMap.Layers.Add(MyLayer);

        translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
    }

    void pin_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("started");
    }

    void pin_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("moving");
         //how do a get the coordonites while I'm moving the pin?
    }

    void pin_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("completed");
    }
}
```

Aby ideas how to make the pin draggeble? If I set pin.AllowDrop=true it throws NotImplementedException.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not for phone, but for Win8 but maybe this tutorial could help? [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2013/10/03/draggable-pushpins-in-bing-maps-net.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bingdevcenter/archive/2013/10/03/draggable-pushpins-in-bing-maps-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thinking a little differently...

The solution I used for [NZ Topo Map](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-nz/store/app/nz-topo-map/b861ab51-a68d-456f-9ae4-cbed66736b36) was to overlay a cross-hair over the map so the user could position the pin precisely by dragging the map instead of dragging a pin. I would then use an app bar with a tick and a cross for "create pin" and "cancel".

Just an alternative UI idea for you to mull over that might be easier to implement and maybe easier for the user.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the move events on the mouse events on the map. This will let you be able to track where the user has moved to. Essentially you would add a mouse down event to the pushpin which would set a flag to capture to allow dragging the pin. Then you would use the mouse move event on the map to reposition the pushpin and the mouse up event on the map to turn the dragging flag off. You will also likely want to display panning of the map. Try capturing the center value when the mouse down event fires, then set the center of the map to this value constantly on the mouse move event when the drag flag it turned on.